# Change menus depending on controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a master-page, how can I know, which controller I am currently using? Is there some kind of context-object, that can give me that sort of information?

#### Standard menu

```
<ul>
<li>Fire</li>
<li>Ice</li>
<li>Water</li>
</ul>
```

#### Menu if I am in the water-controller

```
<ul>
<li>Fire</li>
<li>Ice</li>
<li class="selected">Water</li>
</ul>
```

If I have a menu in my Site.master, where each menu-item refers to a different controller, how can I highlight each menu-item depending on, which controller I am currently in?

I know I can get the url from request.Servervariables and then work some string-magic, but there must be a better way - some kind of context-object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two helper methods I use for checking if its the current controller or even current action. The you can use the helpers to determine whether to add class="selected" or not.

```
public static bool IsCurrentController(this HtmlHelper helper, 
                                       string controllerName)
{
    string currentControllerName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.
                                   Values["controller"];

    if (currentControllerName.Equals(controllerName,
        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public static bool IsCurrentAction(this HtmlHelper helper, string actionName, 
                                   string controllerName)
{
    string currentControllerName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData
                                   .Values["controller"];
    string currentActionName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData
                               .Values["action"];

    if (currentControllerName.Equals(controllerName,
        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && 
        currentActionName.Equals(actionName, 
                                 StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The ViewContext property of the ViewMasterPage contains the Controller and RouteData for the request.  You could look at the type name of the controller or the `controller` key in the route data to find out which controller was invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a

> ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Name

That should do it.